# Is the jQuery UI Touch library aliased?

Tags: jquery

I see that the beginning lines of the jQuery UI Touch Puch are this :

```
(function ($) {

    // Detect touch support
    $.support.touch = 'ontouchend' in document;
```

and that the ending line is this:

```
})(jQuery);
```

Does that mean that dollar sign inside this code is aliased?  We're running into problems of having different versions of jQuery running on the same page (Adobe Edge animations requiring an older version and our application doing the latest / greatest drag drop from a new version).  We'd like to start aliasing our code to a different variable and want to make sure we have all our versions covered.  Is this library already aliased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function (jQ) {     // this is a reference to jQuery, see last line

  // Detect touch support
  jQ.support.touch = 'ontouchend' in document;// but than use your reference inside your fn

})(jQuery);
```

or with `jQuery.noConflict()`:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function ($) {     // remap '$' to 'jQuery' (see last line)

  // Detect touch support
  $.support.touch = 'ontouchend' in document;// use '$' freely

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: So the library currently is not aliased and we would have to replace all dollar sign instances even though it is a passed in variable?

Comment: yes, or rather take a look at how to do it with `.noConflict()`. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/